# Error C2664: невозможно преобразовать аргумент 1 из "std::string" в "char *". Отсутствуют экземпляры конструктора, соответствующие списку аргументов

Tags: c++, строки, классы, char

Source.cpp

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include "Hospital.h"
#include "Patient.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char strHospital[25], strSpecialization[25], strCity[25], strSurename[25], strName[25], strPatronymic[25], strDepartment[25], strDisease[25];
    int iMonth, iDay, iYear;
    char chKey1, chKey2, chRep;
    do {
        cout << "Do you want to know a Hospital information?" << endl;
        cout << "Y//N" << endl;
        cin >> chKey1;
        if (chKey1 == 'Y' || chKey1 == 'y')
        {
            cout << "Please enter a Hospital data:" << endl;
            cout << endl;
            cout << "Enter hospital name - ";
            cin >> strHospital;
            cout << "Enter specialization - ";
            cin >> strSpecialization;
            cout << "Enter city - ";
            cin >> strCity;
            cout << endl;
            Hospital objHospital(strHospital, strSpecialization, strCity);
            objHospital.Show();
        }
        cout << "Do you want to know a Patient information?" << endl;
        cout << "Y//N" << endl;
        cin >> chKey2;
        if (chKey2 == 'Y' || chKey2 == 'y')
        {
            cout << "Please enter a Patient data:" << endl;
            cout << endl;
            cout << "Enter patient Surename - ";
            cin >> strSurename;
            cout << "Enter patient Name - ";
            cin >> strName;
            cout << "Enter patient Patronymic - ";
            cin >> strPatronymic;
            cout << "Enter patient Department - ";
            cin >> strDepartment;
            cout << "Enter patient Disease - ";
            cin >> strDisease;
            cout << "Enter patient Date of Birth(Day, Month, Year) - ";
            cin >> iDay;
            cin >> iMonth;
            cin >> iYear;
            Patient objPatient(strSurename, strName, strPatronymic, strDepartment, strDisease, iMonth, iDay, iYear);
            objPatient.ShowPatient();
        }
        cout << "Do you want to work with programm again?" << endl;
        cout << "Y//N" << endl;
        cin >> chRep;
    } while (chRep == 'Y' || chRep == 'y');
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Hospital.h

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;

// створення класу
class Hospital
{
private:
    string strHospital, strSpecialization, strCity; // опис змінних
public:
    // Конструктор за умовчанням
    Hospital() {};
    // Конструктор опису змінних 
    Hospital(char* chHospital, char* chSpecialization, char* chCity);
    // Конструктор копіювання   
    Hospital(const Hospital &Hosp) {
        this->strHospital = Hosp.strHospital;
        this->strSpecialization = Hosp.strSpecialization;
        this->strCity = Hosp.strCity;
    }

    //сетери
    void setHospital       (char* chHospital);
    void setSpecialization (char* chSpecialization);
    void setCity           (char* chCity);

    //гетери
    string getHospital(void)       { return strHospital;       }
    string getSpecialization(void) { return strSpecialization; }
    string getCity(void)           { return strCity;           }

    // перевірити правильність введення слів у введених даних
    bool isValidAllName(char*);
    //вивід
    void Show();

    //віртуальний деструктор
    virtual ~Hospital() {}
};

//Конструктори
Hospital::Hospital(char* chHospital, char* chSpecialization, char* chCity) {
    setHospital(chHospital);
    setSpecialization(chSpecialization);
    setCity(chCity);
}

// перевірка  назви 
bool Hospital::isValidAllName(char* word)
{
    char simvol = word[0];
    if (simvol >= 65 && simvol <= 104 || simvol >= 192 && simvol <= 223)
        return true;
    else return false;
}

//Вивід класу
void Hospital::Show() {
    cout << "Hospital Info:" << endl;
    cout << "|" << strHospital << "|" << strSpecialization << "|" << strCity << "|" << endl;
}

// ввести назву лікарні
void Hospital::setHospital(char* Hospital)
{
    bool b = isValidAllName(Hospital);
    try
    {
        if (b)
        {
            this->strHospital = Hospital;   // Запис значення chHospital
        }
        else  throw b;
    }
    catch (bool b)    // ловимо виключення  
    {
        cout << "Not valid Name!" << Hospital << endl;
        this->strHospital = "no name";
    }
}
// ввести назву спеціалізації
void Hospital::setSpecialization(char* Specialization)
{
    bool b = isValidAllName(Specialization);
    try
    {
        if (b)
        {
            this->strSpecialization = Specialization;   // Запис значення chSpecialization
        }
        else  throw b;
    }
    catch (bool b)    // ловимо виключення  
    {
        cout << "Not valid Name!" << Specialization << endl;
        this->strSpecialization = "no name";
    }
}
// ввести назву міста
void Hospital::setCity(char* City)
{
    bool b = isValidAllName(City);
    try
    {
        if (b)
        {
            this->strCity = City;   // Запис значення chCity
        }
        else  throw b;
    }
    catch (bool b)    // ловимо виключення  
    {
        cout << "Not valid Name!" << City << endl;
        this->strCity = "no name";
    }
}
```

Patient.h

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;
/*-----------------------------------ПОХІДНИЙ КЛАС--------------------------------*/
// створення похідного класу
class Patient : public Hospital
{
private:
    string strSurename, strName, strPatronymic, strDepartment, strDisease;
    int iMonth, iDay, iYear;
public:
    // Конструктор за умовчанням
    Patient() {};
    // Конструктор опису змінних 
    Patient(char* chSurename, char* chName, char* chPatronymic, char* chDepartment, char* chDisease, int iMonth , int iDay, int iYear);
        // Конструктор копіювання
    Patient(const Patient &Pat, const Hospital &other) :Hospital(other)
    {
        setPatient((char*)Pat.strSurename.c_str(), (char*)Pat.strName.c_str(), (char*)Pat.strPatronymic.c_str());
        setDepartment((char*)Pat.strDepartment.c_str());
        setDisease((char*)Pat.strDisease.c_str());
        setMonth((int)Pat.iMonth);
        setDay((int)Pat.iDay);
        setYear((int)Pat.iYear);
    }

    //сетери
    void setSurename(char* chSurename)     { this->strSurename = chSurename;     }
    void setName(char* chName)             { this->strName = chName;             }
    void setPatronymic(char* chPatronymic) { this->strPatronymic = chPatronymic; }
    void setDepartment(char* chDepartment) { this->strDepartment = chDepartment; }
    void setDisease(char* chDisease)       { this->strDisease = chDisease;       }
    void setMonth(int iMonth)              { this->iMonth = iMonth;              }
    void setDay(int iDay)                  { this->iDay = iDay;                  }
    void setYear(int iYear)                { this->iYear = iYear;                }
    void setPatient(char* chSurename, char* chName, char* chPatronymic)
    {
        this->strSurename = chSurename;
        this->strName = chName;
        this->strPatronymic = chPatronymic;
    }

    //гетери
    string getSurename(void)     const { return strSurename;                                       }
    string getName(void)         const { return strName;                                           }
    string getPatronymic(void)   const { return strPatronymic;                                     }
    string getDepartment(void)   const { return strDepartment;                                     }
    string getDisease(void)      const { return strDisease;                                        }
    int getMonth(void)           const { return iMonth;                                            }
    int getDay(void)             const { return iDay;                                              }
    int getYear(void)            const { return iYear;                                             }
    string getPatient(void)      const { return strSurename + " " + strName + " " + strPatronymic; }

    //методи
    void ShowPatient();
    bool isValidAllName(char*);

    //віртуальний деструктор
    virtual ~Patient();
};
/*-------------------------------------МЕТОДИ----------------------------------------*/
//конструктор з параметрами
Patient::Patient(char* chSurename, char* chName, char* chPatronymic, char* chDepartment, char* chDisease, int iMonth, int iDay, int iYear)// : Hospital(chHospital, chSpecialization, chCity)
{
    setPatient(chSurename, chName, chPatronymic);
    setDepartment(chDepartment);
    setDisease(chDisease);
    setMonth(iMonth);
    setDay(iDay);
    setYear(iYear);
}

//Вивід класу
void Patient::ShowPatient() {
    cout << "Patient Info: " << endl;
    cout << "S.N.P: " << getPatient() << endl;
    cout << "Department: " << getDepartment() << endl;
    cout << "Disease: " << getDisease() << endl;
    cout << "Date of Birth: " << getDay() << "." << getMonth() << "." << getYear() << endl;
}

// перевірка  назви 
bool Patient::isValidAllName(char* word)
{
    char simvol = word[0];
    if (simvol >= 65 && simvol <= 104 || simvol >= 192 && simvol <= 223)
        return true;
    else return false;
}

inline Patient::~Patient()
{
}
```

Скрины с описанием ошибок:
1[image: 1]
2[image: 2]

Всем спасибо за ответы.)Проблема решена.

Answer (score 2):

Ну все логично: либо переделайте конструктор чтобы он принимал `std::string` либо передавайте туда `char*`

```
Hospital(std::string chHospital, std::string chSpecialization, std::string chCity);
```

Comment: Дополнительно к ответу... Как вариант, можно тип аргументов из char* сделать const char* и воспользоваться следующим видом преобразования std::string к const char* : Hospital objHospital(strHospital.c_str(), strSpecialization.c_str(), strCity.c_str());

Comment: Можно, но в этом случае не нужно, потому что все равно будет создаваться `std::string`. Код полностью на `с++` и не нужно напрямую со строками в стиле `с` работать без лишней необходимости.

Comment: Всё оказалось намного проще. Создал в определении переменных не () 'string', а 'char name[]' массивы 'char strHospital[25], strSpecialization[25], strCity[25], strSurename[25], strName[25], strPatronymic[25], strDepartment[25], strDisease[25];'. И немного подправил код в Patient.h. Рабочий код выше обновил.

Comment: Это точно не проще